# Suggestions on where to relocate a wall register I'm enclosing in a closet? (with labeled floor plan attached). Thank you!

Tags: hvac, walls, heating, closet, register

[image: Floorplan]

**I'm looking for some suggestions on where to relocate the HVAC wall register (shown in red), as I am planning to enclose it in a closet.** It comes from 3x7 rectangular duct into the 2x4 wall and rests at floor level in the wall. **It is fed by a 6" solid pipe (shown in orange)** that runs under the floor parallel to the joists and to the furnace, which is right underneath where the orange line stops. **The entire bedroom is down to the studs.** There is one other floor register on the opposite side of the room. The system is used for heating only.

The basement below is unfinished right at the new closet walls and upward in the plan, and finished right from the new closet walls and below (in the plan). I'd prefer to not have to disturb the finished basement drywall. The floor joists are 24" on center and run left to right in the plan. One sits below the uppermost bedroom wall, and another sits 24" from that right below where I plan to frame the closet walls.

**The only ideas I have had so far that seem even potentially feasible (which I do not like very much) are:**

1. Continue the 3x7 rectangular vent upwards to the top of the wall it is currently in, 90 degree turn it to run across the ceiling to the from of the closet, and add a wall register above the closet sliding door. This would be blowing hot air from near the ceiling (not ideal) and also directly over the bed (not ideal).
2. Run the 6" duct under the closet floor to the right hand side of the closet wall and have it come up into the wall via a 3x7 rectangular vent and vent outwards near the floor. This would have it venting straight across the entranceway and towards the right hand side closet, rather than into the room (not ideal).

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That's a really well-stated question, but it may be too opinion-based for our site; let's see if you get a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: why not try leaving it in the closet and moving it later if needed? As long as the closet isn't air-tight, it will be of value in regulating the bedroom temp.

Comment: @dandavis The closet will have a 36" x 80" bifold door that will likely be closed the majority of the time unfortunately.  One of my thoughts was to convert the left closet to open shelving but it wouldn't be as ideal.